# Javascript: group by with aggregation

Tags: javascript, json, group-by

I have a simple json list like the one below

```
{
"myList": [
    {

        "endOfPeriod": 1461362400000,
        "rate": 0.03726378
    },
    {
        "endOfPeriod": 1461535200000,
        "rate": 0.03726378
    },
    {
        "endOfPeriod": 1461967200000,
        "rate": 0.03708314
    },
    {
        "endOfPeriod": 1461708000000,
        "rate": 0.03492851
    },
    {
        "endOfPeriod": 1461794400000,
        "rate": 0.03845068
    },
    {
        "endOfPeriod": 1461621600000,
        "rate": 0.03544827
    }
]
```

}

Where `endOfPeriod` is a unix epoch timestamp. All the timestamps in the example belong to the same month (April 2016), but could be some other periods.
Assuming that I have already converted this json list into an array, and each unix timestamp into a `DD.MM.YYYY` date (I can keep them in unix timestamp too). Is there an efficient way to create a new array with the most recent rate for grouped by month/year?

I have to write code in Javascript.

For instance:

```
20.04.2016 / 0.33
21.04.2016 / 0.55
14.04.2016 / 0.88
02.05.2016 / 1.33
01.05.2016 / 5.44
```

New array must contain:

```
21.04.2016 / 0.55
02.05.2016 / 1.33
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: please add some examples what you like to achieve.

Comment: @NinaScholz: the example of the desired result is at the end of my message :)

Comment: its not realy clear what you have and what you like to get. btw, there is no attempt of any code, you tried.

Comment: Do you want to get last rate of every month?

Comment: Add properties _month_ and _year_ to your _Objects_. Take a look at `_.groupBy` from _lodash/underscore_. `obj = _.groupBy(arr, 'year')`, iterate over `obj` and do what you want with `_.groupBy(subArr, 'month')`

Comment: Make an object whose keys are "MM.YYYY", and the value is an object in that month. Loop through the original array, testing if the date of the current element is higher than the date in the object for its month. if it is, replace it with the current element.

Comment: @matan could you please mark the "correct" answer?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to extract the most recent rate for each month. I would use `lodash`.

```
_.chain(arr)
  .groupBy(function(item) {
    var date = new Date(item.endOfPeriod);
    return date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth();
  })
  .map(function(group) {
    return _.maxBy(group, function(item) {
      return item.endOfPeriod;
    });
  })
  .value()
```

We start with a list of objects in the form:

```
{
    "endOfPeriod" : 1464818400000,
    "rate" : 0.05
}
```

The `chain()` function wraps the list into a lodash object.

Then, we group elements by year and month. After the `groupBy()`, we have the following structure (note that getMonth() is 0-based in Javascript, hence a value of 3 corresponds to April, and so on):

```
{
  "2016-3" : [array of objects in April 2016],
  "2016-4" : [array of objects in May 2016]
  ...
}
```

Then, for each group, we take the item with maximum `endOfPeriod`.

Finally, `value()` unwraps the lodash object back into a plain Javascript array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a result without using `lodash`. But for me it's better not to reinvent the wheel.

```
const myList = [
  {
    "endOfPeriod": 1461362400000,
    "rate": 0.03726378
  },
  {
    "endOfPeriod": 1461535200000,
    "rate": 0.03726378
  },
  {
    "endOfPeriod": 1461967200000,
    "rate": 0.03708314
  },
  {
    "endOfPeriod": 1461708000000,
    "rate": 0.03492851
  },
  {
    "endOfPeriod": 1461794400000,
    "rate": 0.03845068
  },
  {
    "endOfPeriod": 1461621600000,
    "rate": 0.03544827
  }
];

const res = myList.reduce((prev, current) => {
  const date = new Date(current.endOfPeriod);
  const month = date.getMonth();
  const year = date.getFullYear();

  const key = `${year}-${month}`;

  if (prev[key] && prev[key].endOfPeriod < current.endOfPeriod) {
    prev[key] = current;
  } else {
    prev[key] = current;
  }

    return prev;
}, {});


const finalResult = Object.keys(res).map((key) => {
  return {
    key: res[key].rate
  }
});

console.log(finalResult);
```